Storing the pages visited by the user locally in the Angular project
In the Angular project, I want to store the pages visited by the user in the user's local area and create a list of my recent visits. I tried this using both localStorage and sessionStorage, but I cannot access any URLs other than the router URLs defined in the project. What approach should I follow in this regard?

A tab knowing about other tabs violates the user privacy, your application should only worry about your application right?

This is true, but it would be enough for me to save only the urls in its own tab. I do this to make it easier for the user in the application.

Firstly, you cannot access access Url's that are not defined in your Router, because they're not actually handled by Angular. If that's what you're after, then I'd have to disappoint you with a simple 'It's not possible'.
However you can still use Router to store any recent visits to the url's in your application:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.storePage(event.urlAfterRedirects);
      }
    });
  }

  private storePage(url: string) {
    let recentVisits = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recentVisits') || '[]');
    recentVisits.unshift(url);
    localStorage.setItem('recentVisits', JSON.stringify(recentVisits));
  }
}


Yes, I used this method too. It wasn't what I wanted but there's nothing else to do :) thank you
